# Multiple iSCSI LUNs to one Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage-area-network, iscsi, lun

I'm reasonably sure i'm ok to do this, but I would love some confirmation.

Simple question, can I have two LUNs from the same SAN attached to the same server?

More detail:

I have a HP MSA2000 SAN, connecting to multiple Win 2008 R2 servers over iSCSI with MPIO. Each server connects to a single LUN, using Windows native iSCSI connection.

Can I remove the LUN from server A and attach it to Server B without setting up a new iSCSI connection? My main concern would if the original LUN connected to Server B got upset about this new LUN encroaching on its territory.

Just to be clear, i'm not concerned about moving the original LUN from Server A - I know it's not best practice, but i've done it before and we have a good backup of the data.

Any help greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Ross

edit: I meant to say, these LUNs hold nothing but bog standard data, there's no VMs or SQL or anything else awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: yes. This is done all the time - there's nothing preventing multiple LUNs (either FC or iSCSI) from one SAN going to the same server. As an added twist to the simple answer: if you have one LUN going to multiple servers, you will have to ensure you either have only one server mounting it read/write or that you have a multi-initiator capable filesystem on that LUN.

Answer (score 1):

> can I have two LUNs from the same SAN attached to the same server

Yes, easily - glad you checked though!

Comment: Thanks - i'd vote you up, but i'm still not privileged enough.

Comment: I'll live :) cheers